# Highcharts export charts as image on serverside with php

Tags: php, highcharts, export

I've searched on the web for my problem and I found some solutions talking about phantomjs or batik. I tried to use these methods but i failed.
I think it's because i didn't understand very well what I have to do.

Can someone please explain me clearly and step by step what do I have to do ?

Comment: Take look at example: http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts

Comment: Thanks but i've already seen that and read it a lot of times. I still don't understand how to do it

Comment: In related links like https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server/phantomjs you acn find howto prepare your own server. Then when exporting server will works, only what need is paste url to your server in Highcharts (exporting options http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.url)

Comment: So if i understand well, phantomjs is needed to be installed on the server itself ?

Comment: Yes, phantomJS is needed.

Answer (score 4):

There is an easier option if you don't mind calling a third party server (i.e. you have to be ok with your data being passed unprotected across the internet). Highcharts has their own export server that you can just call with your highcharts config object.

Check out their demo at http://export.highcharts.com/. You can use chrome inspection's network tab to see what the call looks like and duplicate it yourself. Basically you just do the following:

- Make a POST request to http://export.highcharts.com/
- Pass an x-www-form-urlencoded body where you change the options key to the
  highcharts config object that matches your chart. Here's an example:

  ```
  async:true
  content:options
  type:image/png
  width:
  scale:
  constr:Chart
  callback:
  options: {{Your config Object here}}
  ```
- Their server will respond with a string like 'files/somename.png' which you can then retrieve by calling http://export.highcharts.com/files/somename.png

I would suggest saving that image immediately on your server as I'm not sure how long they keep it alive for.

Their service is explained on their FAQ page at http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions

And they give an explanation of the arguments you can pass to the server at http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts#post-param

If you do still need to run your own export server then take a look at this post. Highcharts has good instructions on how to do it with example code: http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts

Comment: Hi, do you know why when I'm exporting the highchart server-side I have a black image? I followed the same instruction but always I have black image with even export button shown in the image

Comment: I do not know, sorry. But if you google for `highcharts black image` there are others who have had that same problem - not always specifically with this offline service but maybe their answers could help you. If not, maybe submit a new question and provide a code snippet to demonstrate what you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it, it seems that the issue was in imagemagic

Comment: Great solution!!!. It saved my times. Thanks a lot....